# Google Maps API does not mark the correct position on the map

Tags: javascript, laravel, google-maps

I am looking for a way to display a map with position through latitude and longitude.

I use the following code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Simple Map</title>
        <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
        <style type="text/css">
          /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
           * element that contains the map. */
          #map {
            height: 100%;
          }
    
          /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
          html,
          body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
          }
        </style>
        <script>
    
          const lat = @json($latitud);
          const lon = @json($longitud);
          let map;
    
          function initMap() {
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
              center: { lat: lat, lng: lon },
              zoom: 8,
            });
          }
        </script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="map"></div>
    
        <!-- Async script executes immediately and must be after any DOM elements used in callback. -->
        <script
          src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MICLAVE&callback=initMap&libraries=&v=weekly"
          async
        ></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

From the search box I get the latitude and longitude as follows:

```
Livewire.emit ('getLatitude', place.geometry ['location']. Lat ());
Livewire.emit ('getLength', place.geometry ['location']. Lng ());
```

Latitude and longitude I get it through Google SearchBox I save the values ​​and pass them in the variables:

```
const lat = @json($latitud);
const lon = @json($longitud);
```

These values ​​have already been verified and they are fine.

The problem is that it takes me to the place but in an enlarged way, for example if I want to show a neighborhood, it shows me the entire city.

[image]

I already looked everywhere and I can't find the reason.

Comment: How large is a neighbourhood? How large is the city? You say you need to view a neighbourhood but what exactly constitutes a neighbourhood? Regardless - one way to do this might be to add a circle of a specified radius at the same location as the marker, find the bounds of that circle and zoom to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest changing `zoom: 8` to a larger number, like `zoom: 12` or bigger.

It sounds like your map is centered correctly, but showing too large of an area.  The zoom parameter can help adjust that!

Answer (score 0):

As per the comment above - one way in which you could ensure that you view as small a region as you need would be to add an invisible circle to the map at the same location specified as the map centerpoint and use the `bounds` of the circle to apply to the map.. ie `map.fitBounds( circle.getBounds() )`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Simple Map</title>
        <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
        <style type="text/css">
            #map {
                height:100vh;
                width:100%;
            }
            html,
            body {
                height: 100vh;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
        </style>
        <script>
            /*
            const lat = @json($latitud);
            const lon = @json($longitud);
            */
            const lat = -34.606247;
            const lon =  -58.402056;

            let map;
            let radius=100; // adjust this to change apparent zoom level

            function initMap() {
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
                    center: { lat:lat, lng:lon },
                    zoom: 8,
                });
                let circle=new google.maps.Circle({
                    map:map,
                    center:map.getCenter(),
                    radius:radius,
                    visible:false
                });
                map.fitBounds( circle.getBounds() );
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="map"></div>
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=apikey&callback=initMap" async></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Once the map has been `zoomed-in` you could remove the circle if you wish - `circle.setMap(null);` but will not make much difference either way.

[A JSFiddle to illustrate this in action](https://jsfiddle.net/RamRaider/2sLza9j0/)